# How to reflect an array over a bottom-left to top-right diagonal?

Tags: java

Alright, so I know a top left to a bottom right diagonal line is easy enough to reflect over, you just transpose the array by flipping the coordinates. Now I have this assignment that wants me to reflect a picture object over a diagonal. It's easy enough, I figured out most of it, but I'm getting an error that says my coordinates are out of bounds.

```
for (int i=0; i<v.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < v.getHeight() - i; j++)
        {
            Pixel pixel = v.getPixel(i, j);
            Pixel reflectPixel = v.getPixel(v.getWidth() - j,v.getHeight() - i);
            int amountRed = pixel.getRed();
            int amountBlue = pixel.getBlue();
            int amountGreen = pixel.getGreen();
            reflectPixel.setBlue(amountBlue);
            reflectPixel.setRed(amountRed);
            reflectPixel.setGreen(amountGreen);
        }
    }
```

Now I'm pretty sure I have the correct coordinates of what I'm supposed to mirror, and it's one of the loops that's the problem.

What I was thinking was the first loops runs across the array horizontally, and the second loop runs vertically (The opposite of what arrays usually are). If I have the vertical portion of the loop stop at progressively higher and higher points, I'd have the line I had to reflect over. I did this by subtracting the variable i from it.

The code won't even compile because either the loop demands a pixel out of the area of the picture, or the reflectPixel variable is set to an invalid coordinate. I can't figure out which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I forgot to subtract one from the coordinates of the reflectPixel object. As a result, it was set to a pixel that was just outside the border of the picture.

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I should delete this or leave it up, since I solved my own problem but others can benefit from it too.